# Which Lifecycle hook after axios get but before DOM render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to render my DOM, dependent on some data I'm returning from an `axios get`. I can't seem to get the timing right. The `get` is in the `created` hook, but there is a delay between the `get` and actually receiving the data. Basically if there is info in `seller_id` then I need to show the `cancel` button, otherwise don't. Here is my code:

this is in my `created` hook

```
axios.get('https://bc-ship.c9users.io/return_credentials').then(response => {
      this.seller_id = response.data.seller_id;
      this.selected_marketplace = response.data.marketplace;      
      this.token = response.data.auth_token;
});
```

and then this is the logic to show or hide the button. I've tried `created, mounted, beforeUpdate, and updated` all with no luck. I've also tried `$nextTick` but I can't get the timing correct. This is what I have currently:

```
beforeUpdate: function () {
// this.$nextTick(function () {
  function sellerIdNotBlank() {
    var valid = this.seller_id == '';
    return !valid;
  }
  if(sellerIdNotBlank()){
    this.show_cancel_button = true;
  }
// })
},
```

Comment: Why does `v-if` or `v-show`/`v-hide` not work for you there?

Comment: Yea that works fine, its setting the variable that `v-if` is looking at.. so its `v-if="show_cancel_button"` and I need to set `show_cancel_button` correctly

Comment: Did you define the `show_cancel_button` in your data object? And why don't you directly set the value of it inside the get callback of axios? Vue-JS reactivity should pick up the new value and update the view

Comment: Default `show_cancel_button` to true in your data and set `this.show_cancel_button = false` in the callback of your `axios.get`.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand your problem, but: The `this` inside of the `sellerIdNotBlank` function is not going to reference the Vue instance. So `this.seller_id` is always going to be `undefined`. So `sellerIdNotBlank()` is always going to return `false`.

Comment: Actually, `this` should be `undefined` in that scope, so the code you've shared should be throwing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'seller_id' of undefined"

Comment: @puelo thank you! Not sure why I wasn't doing that before! But I did and its perfect now. Thanks for getting me out of my code rut!!

Comment: @Bert exactly! thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, it is pointless to get your data from backend and try to sync with Vue.js lifecycle methods. It never works.

Also, you should avoid `beforeUpdate` lifecycle event. It is often a code smell. `beforeUpdate` is to be used **only when you have some DOM manipulations done manually** and you need to adjust them again before Vue.js attempt to re-render.

Further, `show_cancel_button` is a very good candidate for a computed property. Here is how component will look:

```
const componentOpts = {

    data() {
        return {
            seller_id: '',
            // ... some more fields
        };
    },

    created() {
        axios.get('https://bc-ship.c9users.io/return_credentials').then(response => {
            this.seller_id = response.data.seller_id;
            this.selected_marketplace = response.data.marketplace;      
            this.token = response.data.auth_token;
        });
    },

    computed: {

        show_cancel_button() {
            return this.seller_id !== '';
        }

    }
}
```